# Samsung Galaxy S kill my android app on music play

Tags: android, media-player, nullpointerexception, galaxy

I have written an app which plays background music with MediaPlayer. I am now testing the app and it works on the HTC Desire perfectly, but when I try to test it on Samsung Galaxy S it dies with a NullPointer exception on the following part:

```
mp_bg_music.play();
```

Yes, I had used `Mediaplayer.create` and as I said it work on HTC Desire! Any idea why my Samsung Galaxy S would fail to run the same program as HTC Desire? Are there any additional things that I should be aware of before I try to play the music? Do I need to grant more uses-permission to app?

Comment: It seems likely that mp_bg_music is `null` on the Galaxy S for some reason. If you add relevant code and logcat output, we may be able to help more but based on what you have in the question, it's unlikely someone will be able to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the AAC to MP3